# How to change the background color of each second row?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, background-color, tablecellrenderer

I try to change the background color of each second row. The problem is that only first COLUMN is affected. Why?

```
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
    {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
        {
            final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.WHITE);
            return c;
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you create `c` using `final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);` what's the value of `column` ? Maybe you're pointing to the first column's cell and setting the background only to that

Comment: What data types do you have in your tables columns?

Comment: You need to provide more information, on how the table was created, i.e. model, renderers, editors.

Comment: *"How to change the background color of each second row?"*  Use the Nimbus PLAF (is one way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, scrap all of what I just wrote.

Attempt #2:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.WHITE);
        return this;
    }
});
```

You need to be returning the current object, not the reference of the super() call.

Comment: This only works if you table only contains String data. It won't work if you have Dates or Integers or Booleans etc.

Answer (score 5):

Using the renderer approach you need to write a custom renderer for every data type in the table. So if you have String, Data, Integer, Boolean you would need to write 4 custom renderers.

See [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for an approach that will allow you to write the code once no matter haw many data types you have in the table. This approach overrides the `preparerrenderer(...)` method of the JTable.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) section of [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial, if you din not specify a renderer for a particular column then the table invokes the table model's `getColumnClass` method to get a default renderer for the column type.

If you have overridden `getColumnClass` method then your approach might not work as expected. For instance:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Column # 1", "Column # 2"}, 0) {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        Class columnClass = Object.class;
        switch(columnIndex) {
            case 0: columnClass = String.class; break;
            case 1: columnClass = Boolean.class; break;
        }
        return columnClass;
    }
};
```

Then doing this:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {// your code here});
```

Won't work for the second column since the `getColumnClass` method will return `Boolean.class` and there's a default cell renderer for that class (`JCheckBox`).

In your case I would suggest you override [JTable.prepareRenderer()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29) method instead to set rows background color independently of the renderer type (`JLabel`, `JCheckBox`, or even custom renderers):

```
JTable table = new JTable(model) {
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.WHITE);
        return c;
    }
};
```